# NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("useremail") value returning null

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am creating login registeration page but there is error. userStoredEmailuser and userStoredPassword returning null when I try to login. Please help for this error.

login code:

```
let useremail=email.text;
let userpassword=password.text;

let userStoredEmail = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("useremail") //return null

let userStoredPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userpassword") //return null

// print(emails);
//  print(userStoredEmail);
```

Registreration code:

```
let useremail=email.text;
let userpassword=password.text;
let userRePassword = RePassword.text;
//check for empty field

//store data

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("useremail", forKey: useremail!)
defaults.setObject("userpassword", forKey: userpassword!)
defaults.synchronize()

let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:"Registration is succesfully complete", preferredStyle:.Alert)
// add an action (button)

alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

presentViewController(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: where you called this `let userStoredEmail = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("useremail") //return null` in viewdidload or else
`

Comment: use value for key property

Comment: in IBAction onclick of button i have called this userstroedEmail @anbu.karthik

Comment: FYI - you really need to migrate to Swift 3. Swift 2 is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is  not

```
defaults.setObject("useremail", forKey: useremail!)
defaults.setObject("userpassword", forKey: userpassword!)
```

it is, you are wrongly saved the value to userdefaults

```
defaults.setObject(useremail!, forKey: "useremail")
defaults.setObject(userpassword!, forKey: "userpassword")
```

no need of `synchronize()` - it will automatically update the userdefaults

Comment: I'm really glad to see the good advice about not needing synchronize. Too many people use it without understanding what it does (and does not). +1

Answer (score 2):

You are storing "key" as value in `NSUserDefaults` so you need to write as

```
defaults.setObject(useremail!, forKey:"useremail")
defaults.setObject(userpassword!, forKey:"userpassword")
```

instead of

```
defaults.setObject("useremail", forKey: useremail!)
defaults.setObject("userpassword", forKey: userpassword!)
```